# Unable to get property 'DestinationType' of undefined or null reference in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am beginner for ionic apps and i am trying to capture pic using below code but i am getting exception like **Unable to get property 'DestinationType' of undefined or null reference** and i have added below two plugins to my project

can some one help me please

$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera-preview
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/camera-preview

### home.ts:

```
export class HomePage {

  public base64Image: string;
  public photos : any;

  constructor(private camera: Camera) {
  }

  takePhoto() {
    const options : CameraOptions = {
      quality: 50, // picture quality
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }
    this.camera.getPicture(options) .then((imageData) => {
      this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}
```

### home.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="home">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
      Hello World, this is my camera app

      <button (click)="takePhoto()">Take a Picture</button>

      Latest Picture:
      <img [src]="base64Image" *ngIf="base64Image" />
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

### app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    CameraPreview
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: public camera: Camera; 
Is Camera an interface? if so, can you paste the code of Camera? else, you have to define an interface and assign it.

Comment: @Jacob Nelson i edited my code i am getting exception now--> Uncaught (in promise):Error:StaticInjectionError(AppModule) [HomePage->Camera];StaticInjectionError(Platform:core)

Comment: I think you need to `Import` `CameraPreview` instead of `Camera`?

Comment: i added please check now

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use *Camera* and not *CameraPreview*.
You have to use Angular's dependency injection to `inject` an instance of Camera to your component. Add the Camera to the constructor (and remove the `public camera: Camera`)

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

constructor(public camera: Camera) { }
```

You can follow the [example](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/) from Ionic.

You can read about [DI in the Angular's doc](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection).

Comment: Uncaught (in promise):Error:StaticInjectionError(AppModule)
[HomePage->Camera];StaticInjectionError(Platform:core)

Comment: i am getting above exception when i updated as your said

Comment: Did you add the Camera to the providers array from app.module.ts as explained here? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/#Add_Plugins_to_Your_App_Module

Comment: 'Camera' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `cordova-plugin-camera-preview`

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera-preview
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/camera-preview
```

You need to `import`

```
import { CameraPreview } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview';
```

Here is an `example`

```
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewPictureOptions, CameraPreviewOptions, CameraPreviewDimensions } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview';

constructor(private cameraPreview: CameraPreview) { }


// camera options (Size and location). In the following example, the preview uses the rear camera and display the preview in the back of the webview
const cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: window.screen.width,
  height: window.screen.height,
  camera: 'rear',
  tapPhoto: true,
  previewDrag: true,
  toBack: true,
  alpha: 1
};

// start camera
this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts).then(
  (res) => {
    console.log(res)
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err)
  });


}
```

Then add **`CameraPreview`** to **providers** in `app-module`

```
import { CameraPreview } from '@ionic-native/camera-preview';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    CameraPreview
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Official Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview/)

Comment: @AbhiRam, try adding `CameraPreview` instead of `camera`. Please check my answer once.

Comment: Unexpected value 'CameraPreview' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: getting this exception

Comment: can you please add your `app module`?

Comment: no I think `camera` works only in mobile because it is `native plugin`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172137/discussion-between-abhiram-and-sravan).

Comment: @AbhiRam, you can accept and upvote my answer, if you find it useful. :-)